# Caption and title in img alt tag are the same?

Tags: images, query

I'm currently on WP 3.6 and noticed an unpredictable behaviour with the alt attributes generated by WP.

If I have an image title, the title appears in the alt.
If I have a caption, the caption replaces the alt.

What can I do to prevent the image title from appearing in the alt field? I want to keep it empty if there are no image captions.

Comment: I checked for it and it's not happening at my side. Can you tell me the steps to reproduce it?

Comment: What function and related arguments are you using to print images? In WP there are at least 4/5 methods to print images...

Comment: I used the default [gallery] shortcode to generate the images and set all link="file".